# How can I add a response header when running a SPA in Azure Web Apps using PM2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, pm2

I have a React SPA which runs in Azure Web Apps, Node stack (Node 16 LTS), via the startup command:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

I would like to add a response header (specifically, a Content-Security-Policy header) for every outgoing request.

Things I have tried:

- adding a .htaccess file
- adding a web.config file
- looking for an evironment setting, or way to configure either pm2, or node

I don't have any node code to change (so I can't add headers there), and doing it in React feels "too late" - I think it's something that node on the server, or Azure needs to do.

My nuclear option is to wrap Front Door around it and do it there, but I'm hoping there is way to achieve this without that.

Comment: refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/development/add-http-response-header-web-site

Comment: Er, that’s a page about on-premise IIS? I’m not understanding the relavence?

Answer (score 4):

I spent several days with the same thing and I found that pm2 serves the React SPA through the **Serve.js** configuration file located in */usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API/*.

Inside, you'll find the **http.createServer** function with response and result parameters. You can add headers to the response parameter using **response.setHeader** (Node.js method). But there is a problem, any modification that we make outside of /home is not persistent, so we have to carry out a few extra steps:

1. Enter the console of the machine through SSH (in the Azure portal, left side menu, Developer Tools section, SSH option, and Go).

[image: SSH Option in Azure Portal]

2. Copy the pm2 folder into /home/site

> cp -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/ /home/site/

3. Modify the Serve.js file, adding the headers in http.createServer. You can do it in the console through vi/nano, or graphically through the KuduLite portal (https://[NAME-OF-YOUR-SITE].scm.azurewebsites.net/newui), File Manager, Edit option.

> http.createServer(function (request, response) {
>     response.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src ... ");

4. In the Azure portal, enter the Web App Service configuration (in the left side menu, Settings section). In General Settings, replace the Startup Command field with this text:

> /home/site/pm2/bin/pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa --name APP_NAME

(applies for Node 16 as well).

[image: Startup Command Fixed for SPA]

5. Save changes, wait for the confirmation notification and restart the service.

Maybe not the most 'best practice' solution, but I didn't find another way that I could overwrite pm2's Serve.js settings without having to copy the whole folder.

I apologize for my English translation.

Comment: This worked for me but I am not entirely sure of any side effects this may cause.

Comment: This works but every time you make any change to your app services like changing the runtime, this copied folder gets wiped out leaving our app broken. The ideal solution is to front your app service with an AppGateway and set the headers there.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach would be fronting your SPA webapp with an AppGateway and rewrite headers in the app gateway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url

If we copy pm2 and use it, any change to the app service like changing the runtime will remove the copied folder leaving our app broken.

Answer (score -6):

In App Service Linux, React application can be started with PM2, npm start or custom command.

The container automatically starts your app with PM2 when one of the common Node.js files is found in your project:

[image]

Also Note that Starting from Node 14 LTS, the container doesn't automatically start your app with PM2. To start your app with PM2, set the startup command to `pm2 start <.js-file-or-PM2-file> --no-daemon`.

Be sure to use the `--no-daemon` argument because PM2 needs to run in the foreground for the container to work properly.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux

Comment: You did not answer his question, how to add http response header.